# Why was super shredder so weak?

Tags: plot-explanation, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-1990, tmnt-secret-of-the-ooze

In [Ninja Turtles 1 (1990)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100758/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4) regular Shredder is crushed in a trash truck by Casey Jones, but not before a battle with the turtles and splinter, but in [Ninja Turtles 2 (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103060/), super Shredder is simply buried in rubble from the pier falling in on him after he decimated the pillars, no fight what-so-ever. Why did the producers/director decide to end shredder in this fashion? It was far too simplistic especially compared to his defeat in part 1. It seems like such a cop-out especially considering the potential for an epic battle scene.

Not only that, why did he survive from part 1 to part 2, but not from part 2 to part 3 when his defeat was so simple in part 2?

Comment: Well, part 3 had them time travel back to feudal Japan, so I'd say that's why for that question. It's possible he DID survive, but given they traveled back in time several hundred years he wouldn't have been the main fixture of the third movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first TMNT received some negative criticism for the amount of violence in the movie so the producers banned the use of weapons in the second movie:

> Due to backlash from parents over the darker and more violent tone of the first movie, the producers decided to not allow the Turtles to use their weapons for the entirety of this film.
>   [IMDB Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103060/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)

Because of this, the director/writers had to find a way to defeat Shredder in the most non-violent way which is why you see him basically defeat himself.

Comment: Oh man, what a bunch of bs. I'm a parent and I want to see violence, damn it!! :)

Comment: Compared to movies nowadays, it's quite mild.The outcry wasn't just from parents however, it also came from people making the movie. Judith Hoag (who played April) as well as Jim Henson brought the issue of violence up to the producers before and after the movie was released.